# Convert Complexe arrays to XML Laravel

Tags: xml, laravel

I'm building a Web Service where user receive data depending on the format desired (Json/Xml), Making Json response is not the problem , I get multiple arrays from an operation and i should return it to the user as Xml.
 when there is only one array i can do it using this bundle `spatie\array-to-xml\`
but if there is more than one array i get an error:

> DOMException in ArrayToXml.php line 40:Invalid Character Error

here is the the array returned (what i want to convert ):

```
Array("0"=>array(...),"1"=>array(....)).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Package - [Array2Xml](https://packagist.org/packages/openlss/lib-array2xml), to change array to XML like this:

```
$books = [1 => 'A', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'C'];
$xml = Array2XML::createXML('books', $books);
```

> See [Array2XML Docs](http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-xml-to-array-in-php-xml2array/) for more reference

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i get this error
[Array2XML] Illegal character in tag name. tag: 0 in node: books

Comment: I've updated the answer, please have a look. Remember to import the package correctly.

Comment: what i have actually is something like array(array1,array2....) will that work with this package ?

Comment: Yup, I hope so, try it out

Comment: sorry i still have [Array2XML] Illegal character in tag name. tag: 0 in node: books